# Performance benchmark of native android map vs webview map, what parameters can be included in the benchmark

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, benchmarking, google-maps-android-api-2, performance-testing

I am trying to compare native google maps (v2) vs the embeddable HTML version encapsulated in a webview on android. While it's pretty evident that the native maps are smoother and faster, I must prove that somehow. I have been searching on the internet for quite some time and did not seem to find any existing benchmarks. Does anybody know someone who actually done something similar? I am already thinking of creating such benchmark of my own, but how can the performance actually be measured? My ideas so far are:

- Measure rendering of different number of markers, polylines, etc...
- Measure map tile loading (maybe not possible at all)
- Somehow measure the lag when dragging the map. This must be somehow based on the map events, but the native GoogleMap class does not seem to have something like onDragListener.

If you have any ideas or know some existing resource, please help me!

**-----------------EDITED 03.01.2014----------------**

I already started creating my benchmark but now I am struggling with some strange issues - see [this question for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20482647/measure-complete-time-of-adding-showing-an-array-of-markers-to-google-maps-v3).

The source code of the first version of my benchmark can be found [here](https://github.com/martindobrev/MapBenchmark). It currently does not include automated testing. Nevertheless when experimenting with adding different number of markers and lines you can get an idea of how slower html maps are. I have also uploaded a simple demo on youtube, to view it [click here](http://youtu.be/ze9V7SImBc4)

Comment: First of all WHY do you need to compare these two? And do benchmarking?

Comment: I am currently writing my master thesis. It's about cross-platform-development for mobile devices. As a result I have to choose one of the existing approaches, implement a prototype of a predefined application for Android, iOS and WP8 and then evaluate the chosen approach. Since geolocation and map interaction are the main functions of the application, I already decided that the map shall be a native component based on my personal experience. But according to my supervisor I must somehow base my decision on facts or measurable tests (at least for one of the platforms)

Comment: That is cool idea. No one has done it till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Your topic is pretty interesting, but remember if you are going for google maps on mobile vs web, there is mobile v2 and javascript v3. Javascript google maps has some added functionalities that mobile does not offer, you can refer the docs to find out. AND You can perform on various parameters like.
1. Time it takes to load (display) the map on the screen. 
2. As you mentioned rendering on the map.
3. Performance issues on low bandwidth.
4. UI and UX.
5. Reliability
6. User Satisfaction
7. Implementation (Complete off topic but since you are doing a thesis I will recommend that)
8. Features
9. At last pricing. (I think upto 20000 calls per day is free  on one API key on javascript v3)

**NOTE** 
Anyone feel free to edit and add some more parameters for benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really never thought of Implementation as a parameter - will definitely be useful to include that. This will also result in some additional pages :) I will at first concentrate on googlemaps and on android as the most popular ones. If there is time I will consider adding iOS with their native maps and other web-based maps as BING and OpenStreetMap. I will update the question when it's done. This will definitely take a while since I am currently struggling with other issues :(

Comment: @maddob Its a really good idea for thesis. And please share your benchmarks when done and also consider to do an UP or accept the answer if helped.

Comment: Yeah, of course, sorry, totally forgotten ;) Accept will be given later - when the benchmark is done. Maybe someone else will come up with other nice tips & tricks

Comment: @maddob yeah sure. ;) and don't forget to share the benchmarking results. I am really interested. :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but I was really busy doing other stuff. Unfortunately I was not able to complete the benchmark :( What I came up with is a simple application where you can manually add a number of markers and lines. This has convinced everybody that html maps are not suitable at all for our prototype. Short demo is available at: http://youtu.be/ze9V7SImBc4, the source code can be found on github under: https://github.com/martindobrev/MapBenchmark

Comment: that was a nice benchmark. Native maps FTW. but what about the hard numbers? graphs? charts?

Comment: Unfortunately I was not able to measure the real rendering time of html map components, since the delay comes from the browser-engine itself. For example when 1000 markers are added, javascript code is executed, the elements are added to the DOM and this only takes some milliseconds. This is the only period of time that I was able to measure. After markers are added to the DOM, the browser engine processes their display. Actually on my device, 1000 markers appear after a couple of seconds. I couldn't find any way to measure the complete time (see the link in the description for details)

Comment: okay. glad you completed the thesis and the benchmark video is also good. Anyways I really don't feel like it but if you want to mark the answer as accepted.