# Measure complete time of adding (showing) an array of markers to google maps v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to measure the COMPLETE time (including adding the objects to the DOM) for adding a number of markers to a google map instance, but it does not really work the way I expected. Here is the function I have:

```
    function addMarkers(count) {

        // map is the google.maps.Map object


        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var minLat = Math.min(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
        var maxLat = Math.max(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
        var minLng = Math.min(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());
        var maxLng = Math.max(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());

        var latDifference = maxLat - minLat;
        var lngDifference = maxLng - minLng;
        var latLngArray = new Array();

        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            var lat = minLat + Math.random() * latDifference;
            var lng = minLng + Math.random() * lngDifference;
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            latLngArray.push(latLng);                
        }


        /////////////// MEASUREMENTS STARTING FROM HERE ////////////////////

        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        for (var i = 0; i < latLngArray.length; i++) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: latLngArray[i]
            });
            marker.setMap(map);
        }

        var endTime = new Date().getTime();
        return endTime - startTime;
    }
```

I am testing this code inside a WebView on my Android device. Also tested the same in my browser. Here is a link where you can check it out - http://www.debelacite.com/test/gmap_benchmark.html.

So everything works, the markers are shown, but the time calculated does not really correspond to the real time for adding the markers. For example to show 100 markers the result I get is usually from 50 to 100 milliseconds, but until the markers appear on the screen at least 1-2 seconds pass. How can I get the time for the whole process? I have looked for proper events in the API, but none seem to help :( Am I missing something?

Comment: You need to measure the time from when you start adding markers to the time the map is idle (the map idle event fires).

Comment: I would be willing to bet to keep the UI responsive, Google has programmed the Map API as Pseudo-Async.

Comment: @geocodezip 'idle' does not seem to be called when adding markers :( I have already tried that.

Comment: Sorry, it look like it doesn't (from [the documentation, Map: Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map): idle | None | This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming).  I guess you need to listen for the load event on the icon images, if that can be made to work.

Comment: you can use map's `tilesloaded` event

Comment: tilesloaded does not work either, it only fires when the map tiles are loaded, markers are not considered at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would modify your function like this:

```
function addMarkers(count) {
    // map is the google.maps.Map object
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
    var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var minLat = Math.min(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
    var maxLat = Math.max(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
    var minLng = Math.min(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());
    var maxLng = Math.max(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());

    var latDifference = maxLat - minLat;
    var lngDifference = maxLng - minLng;
    var latLngArray = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var lat = minLat + Math.random() * latDifference;
        var lng = minLng + Math.random() * lngDifference;
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        latLngArray.push(latLng);
    }


    /////////////// MEASUREMENTS STARTING FROM HERE ////////////////////

    var chrono = new Chrono();
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
        chrono.stop();
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(chrono, 'chrono_stops', function (e) {
        var result = e.totalTime();
        console.log(result);
    });

    chrono.start();
    for (var i = 0; i < latLngArray.length; i++) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLngArray[i]
        });
        marker.setMap(map);
    }
}    
function Chrono() {
    this.startTime;
    this.endTime;
}
Chrono.prototype.start = function() {
    this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
};
Chrono.prototype.stop = function() {
    this.endTime = new Date().getTime();
    google.maps.event.trigger(this, "chrono_stops", this);
};
Chrono.prototype.totalTime = function() {
    return this.endTime - this.startTime;
};
```

Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Chrono demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body{ height: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        #map-container{ height: 100%; width: 100%; min-width:500px; min-height:300px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script>
        var map, firstBoundChangedListener,  markers =[];

        function Chrono() {
            this.startTime;
            this.endTime;
        }
        Chrono.prototype.start = function () {
            this.startTime = new Date().getTime();
        };
        Chrono.prototype.stop = function () {
            this.endTime = new Date().getTime();
            google.maps.event.trigger(this, "chrono_stops", this);
        };
        Chrono.prototype.totalTime = function () {
            return this.endTime - this.startTime;
        };

        function addMarkers(count) {
            console.log("Entering addMarkers function...");
            // map is the google.maps.Map object
            var bounds = map.getBounds();
            var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
            var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
            var minLat = Math.min(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
            var maxLat = Math.max(northEast.lat(), southWest.lat());
            var minLng = Math.min(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());
            var maxLng = Math.max(northEast.lng(), southWest.lng());

            var latDifference = maxLat - minLat;
            var lngDifference = maxLng - minLng;
            var latLngArray = new Array();

            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var lat = minLat + Math.random() * latDifference;
                var lng = minLng + Math.random() * lngDifference;
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                latLngArray.push(latLng);
            }

            /////////////// MEASUREMENTS STARTING FROM HERE ////////////////////

            var chrono = new Chrono();

            google.maps.event.addListener(chrono, 'chrono_stops', function (e) {
                var result = e.totalTime();
                console.log(result);
            });

            chrono.start();
            for (var i = 0; i < latLngArray.length; i++) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLngArray[i],
                    title: "Marker: " + i
                });
                markers.push(marker);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "map_changed", function () {
                    console.log("map_changed");
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
            }
            chrono.stop();
            console.log("Leaving addMarkers function...");
        }

        function initialize() {
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), mapOptions);
            firstBoundChangedListener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function () {
                if (firstBoundChangedListener) google.maps.event.removeListener(firstBoundChangedListener);

                addMarkers(10000);
            });

        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---------------------- EDITED ----------------------

To see that open two tabs. In one tab you do whatever you want and in the other tab you run your application (or my modified demo) and you open the Developer Tools and undock it. Then you go back on you another tab (where you're doing what you want). Like that the browser is showing another page but not the page with the demo.

Then you go to the undocked developer tools window and refresh the page (press F5 key). You look at the debug and you wait for the "Leaving addMarkers function...." message, you wait as long as you want so that you know all the possible asynchronouly loaded has finished and then you go to the tab with the **demo**.

You will see as the markers somehow were asynchronously loaded, but it is only the browser rendering them.

Only it seems to me like that, I'm not sure of that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this does not work either :( The tilesloaded event is fired only when the map tiles are loaded. If you start adding markers after the tiles are loaded (either manually or with a timer like 5 seconds ) the chrono.stop event gets never called

Comment: You're right, seems like your method is the correct one, since the marker is bound immediately after you call the `google.maps.Marker.setMap` method. Why is it you think the calculation does not correspond well? Which precision are you looking for? It seems like we look for events telling us the markers has been bounds or loaded since they existed in V2 but seems all that was worked around and they are no loger useful.

Comment: It seems to me that the results of my method give only the time for the iteration of the javascript "for" loop and that the markers are somehow asynchronously loaded. The result is returned before the markers are shown - to see that, try with like 10000 markers. I am not looking for precision here, just reasonable results. Actually I am trying to create a kind of benchmark that compares android native google maps and maps encapsulated in a webview, see this for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20132413/performance-benchmark-of-native-android-map-vs-webview-map-what-parameters-can

Comment: It seems to me is more a browser's 'lag' as he has to show a huge amount of images at once. The browser show the images when the loop finished. The image used (if it is the _by default_ image) is downloaded only on time so there is no asynchronous load there either.

Comment: This totally makes sense, I will try with other elements like polylines

Comment: Same with polylines :(